# Openstack deployment with juju fails connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, juju, openstack

I'm deploying OpenStack using juju. All instances comes up, but it seems that no instances are capable of communicating with the mysql server. Juju status shows:

> hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed"

for neutron-api, glance and nova-cloud-controller.
If I look in juju debug-log, I get messages like

> "Host \'10.51.232.1\' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Users nova, glance, neutron and keystone have been created by the juju charm and can be listed in mysql.
I have looked in /etc/mysql/percona-xtradb-cluster.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and found that bind-address is set to 0.0.0.0
What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error
hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed"

And the issue was that I did not create a space. The network connector that relates units requires that the subnet it's deployed in is related to a space.
you can view this with commands:
juju spaces
juju subnets

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "creating space". Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Pilot6. I'm very new to maas, juju and openstack so I can't give you a very detailed explanation. All I know is that within maas there is an object called "spaces" that is a sort of group for subnets. You would create a space and associate it with a subnet. This is required for relations between applications as it allowes the creation of the "juju-info" interface, that is a default connection interface for relations.
See this: https://juju.is/docs/sdk/integration#heading--implicit-integrations
I don't know a lot of how or why it works. I can only tell you that it solved my issues.